# Possible to pass jdbc options to flyway in the jdbc url?

Tags: db2, flyway

I need to set auto commit for the database connection that flyway is using. Typically for clients I would do this via jdbc options in the jdbc url. I couldn't figure out how to do this using the flyway command-line tool. Is it possible?

Comment: Just to know, why do you need autocommit?

Comment: I'm not using straight DB2. Instead I'm using BigSQL. It appears that BigSQL runs into a self-deadlock when flyway attempts to migrate or init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass options to in the jdbc url.

However, setting autocommit will not work, as Flyway will override this and run each migrate inside a transaction, to make sure it can be rolled back in case of failure.

Comment: Axel, that makes sense accepted your answer. However I couldn't seem to pass options in the jdbc url. What is the correct syntax when using the command-line tool?

Comment: -url=jdbc:db2:... with the db2 url in accordance to http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052342.html